# Query on Queues and Thread Safety

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, thread-safety

Thread-Safety is not an aspect that I have worried about much as the simple apps and libraries I have written usually only run on the main thread, or do not directly modified properties or fields in any classes that I needed to worry about before.

However, I have started working on a personal project that I am using a `WebClient` to download data asynchronously from a remote server.  There is a `Queue<Uri>` that contains a pre-built queue of a series of URI's to download data.

So consider the following snippet (this is not my real code, but something I am hoping illustrates my question:

```
private WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
private Queue<Uri> requestQueue = new Queue<Uri>();

public Boolean DownloadNextASync()
{
    if (webClient.IsBusy)
        return false;

    if (requestQueue.Count == 0)
        return false

    var uri = requestQueue.Dequeue();

    webClient.DownloadDataASync(uri);

    return true;

}
```

If I am understanding correctly, this method is not thread safe (assuming this specific instance of this object is known to multiple threads).  My reasoning is `webClient` could become busy during the time between the `IsBusy` check and the `DownloadDataASync()` method call.  And also, `requestQueue` could become empty between the `Count` check and when the next item is dequeued.

My question is what is the best way to handle this type of situation to make it thread-safe?

This is more of an abstract question as I realize for this specific method that there would have to be an exceptionally inconvenient timing for this to actually cause a problem, and to cover that case I could just wrap the method in an appropriate `try-catch` since both pieces would throw an exception.  But is there another option?  Would a `lock` statement be applicable here?

Comment: Which version of .Net are you targeting? If you have .Net 4.0 or 4.5 your implementation will likely be different from 2.0.

Comment: I'd recommend you consider the Producer-Consumer pattern ... [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'm targeting C# 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting .Net 4.0, you could use the Task Parallel Library for help:

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<Uri>();
var maxClients = 4;

// Optionally provide another producer/consumer collection for the data
// var data = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<Uri,byte[]>>();

// Optionally implement CancellationTokenSource

var clients = from id in Enumerable.Range(0, maxClients)
              select Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        while (!queue.IsCompleted)
        {
            Uri uri;
            if (queue.TryTake(out uri))
            {
                byte[] datum = client.DownloadData(uri); // already "async"
                // Optionally pass datum along to the other collection
                // or work on it here
            }
            else Thread.SpinWait(100);
        }
    });

// Add URI's to search
// queue.Add(...);

// Notify our clients that we've added all the URI's
queue.CompleteAdding();

// Wait for all of our clients to finish
clients.WaitAll();
```

---

To use this approach for progress indication you can use `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` to manage the Event based parallelism:

```
public static Task<byte[]> DownloadAsync(Uri uri, Action<double> progress)
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged
                += (sender, e) => progress(e.ProgressPercentage);
            client.DownloadDataCompleted
                += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (!e.Cancelled)
                    {
                        if (e.Error == null)
                        {
                            source.SetResult((byte[])e.Result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            source.SetException(e.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        source.SetCanceled();
                    }
               };
        });

    return source.Task;
}
```

Used like so:

```
// var urls = new List<Uri>(...);
// var progressBar = new ProgressBar();

Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
       foreach (var uri in urls)
       {
           var task = DownloadAsync(
               uri,
               p =>
                   progressBar.Invoke(
                       new MethodInvoker(
                       delegate { progressBar.Value = (int)(100 * p); }))
               );

           // Will Block!
           // data = task.Result;
       } 
    });
```

Comment: The parallel downloading is an interesting idea.  I had considered trying to find a way to do this in my original design, but wasn't quite sure how to implement it.  As an aside, some of the downloads could take a while, is there a way to report progress back to the GUI thread. That was one of the things I like about doing the `DownloadDataASync()` serially was I could subscribe to the `DownloadProgressChanged` event.  Not a critical requirement, just nice to know if it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  Wasn't quite what I asked for in the question, but the answer let me rethink the design into something that was less of a concern with thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading "Threading In C#" by Joseph Albahari. I have taken a look through it in preparation for my first (mis)adventure into threading and it's pretty comprehensive.

You can read it here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 1):

Both of the thread-safety concerns you raised are valid. Furthermore, the both WebClient and Queue are documented as not being thread-safe (at the bottom of the MSDN docs). For example, if two threads were dequeuing simultaneously, they might actually cause the queue to become internally inconsistent or could lead to non-sensical return values. For example, if the implementation of Dequeue() was something like:

```
1. var valueToDequeue = this._internalList[this._startPointer];
2. this._startPointer = (this._startPointer + 1) % this._internalList.Count;
3. return valueToDequeue;
```

and two threads each executed line 1 before either continued to line 2, then both would return the same value (there are other potential issues here as well). This would not necessarily throw an exception, so you should use a lock statement to guarantee that only one thread can be inside the method at a time:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();

...

lock (this._lock) { 
    // body of method
}
```

You could also lock on the WebClient or the Queue if you know that no-one else will be synchronizing on them.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I think this answer did answer my question as asked the best, but I went with sixlettervariables because his outside of the box solution help improve my design so I didn't have to worry about thread safety nearly as much.  I've tried to give you a few upvotes instead.